# return the result of a query and the total number of rows in a single function

Tags: optimization, codeigniter, count

This is a question as might be focused on working in the best way, if there are other alternatives or is the only way:

Using Codeigniter ...  I have the typical 2 functions of list records and show total number of records (using the page as an alternative). The problem is that they are rather large. Sample 2 functions in my model:

**count Rows:**

```
function get_all_count()
    {
        $this->db->select('u.id_user');
        $this->db->from('user u');
        if($this->session->userdata('detail') != '1')
        {
            $this->db->join('management m', 'm.id_user = u.id_user', 'inner');
            $this->db->where('id_detail', $this->session->userdata('detail'));
            if($this->session->userdata('management') === '1')
            {
                $this->db->or_where('detail', 1);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where("id_profile IN (
                                SELECT
                                e2.id_profile
                                FROM profile e, profile e2, profile_path p, profile_path p2
                                WHERE e.id_profile = " . $this->session->userdata('profile') . "
                                AND p2.id_profile = e.id_profile
                                AND p.path LIKE(CONCAT(p2.path,'%'))
                                AND e2.id_profile = p.id_profile
                                )", NULL, FALSE);

                $this->db->where('MD5(u.id_user) <>', $this->session->userdata('id_user'));
            }
        }       
        $this->db->where('u.id_user <>', 1);
        $this->db->where('flag <>', 3);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();  
    }
```

**results per page**

```
function get_all($limit, $offset, $sort = '')
    {
        $this->db->select('u.id_user, user, email, flag');
        $this->db->from('user u');
        if($this->session->userdata('detail') != '1')
        {
            $this->db->join('management m', 'm.id_user = u.id_user', 'inner');
            $this->db->where('id_detail', $this->session->userdata('detail'));
            if($this->session->userdata('management') === '1')
            {
                $this->db->or_where('detail', 1);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->where("id_profile IN (
                                SELECT
                                e2.id_profile
                                FROM profile e, profile e2, profile_path p, profile_path p2
                                WHERE e.id_profile = " . $this->session->userdata('profile') . "
                                AND p2.id_profile = e.id_profile
                                AND p.path LIKE(CONCAT(p2.path,'%'))
                                AND e2.id_profile = p.id_profile
                                )", NULL, FALSE);

                $this->db->where('MD5(u.id_user) <>', $this->session->userdata('id_user'));
            }
        }
        $this->db->where('u.id_user <>', 1);
        $this->db->where('flag <>', 3);
        if($sort) $this->db->order_by($sort);
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();    
    }
```

You see, I repeat the most of the functions, the difference is that only the number of fields and management pages.

I wonder if there is any alternative to get as much results as the query in a single function. I have seen many tutorials, and all create 2 functions: one to count and another to show results ... Will there be more optimal?

Comment: I guess using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` is not an option?

Comment: something like SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` in your query, something like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS first_name, age FROM table
```

to return the result you can simply create a new array:

```
$result['total'] = $this->db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total")->row_array();
$result['result_array'] = $query->result();
return $result;
```